# Trigger a pipeline in another Gitlab repo multiple times with different variables

Tags: gitlab, cicd

I am trying to trigger a Gitlab pipeline in another Gitlab repository 3 times, each time with different variables. My attempt is as follows:

```yaml
---
include:
  - project: "aap/gitlab-ci"
    ref: "go-pipeline"
    file: "/alpha/pipelines/go_image.yaml"

ice-gitops:
  variables:
    IMAGE_NAME: "ice-gitops"
    GO_TEST: "true"
    DOCKERFILE_PATH: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/build/Dockerfile"
  script:
    - echo "Running the pipeline for Ice Gitops"

ice-gitops-ci:
  variables:
    DOCKERFILE_PATH: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/build/Dockerfile.ci"
    IMAGE_NAME: "ice-gitops-ci"
    GO_TEST: "true"
  script:
    - echo "Running the pipeline for Ice Gitops CI"

ice-gitops-ci-local:
  variables:
    IMAGE_NAME: "ice-gitops-ci-local"
    GO_TEST: "true"
    DOCKERFILE_PATH: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/build/Dockerfile.local"
  script:
    - echo "Running the pipeline for Ice Gitops CI Local"
```

However, this does not lead to the desired result of having all the jobs in the external pipeline to run 3 times. Is there another approach that I can take here?

Comment: do you need to trigger pipeline from `aap/gitlab-ci` project?

Comment: Yes, we are using that pipeline for other repos as well, so it needs to be in that project.